# FTC list of telemarketer phone numbers that have received complaints

Tags: data-request, government, api, telecom

Is the Federal Trade Commission (FTC) list of telemarketer phone numbers that have received complaints available? Supposedly Nomorobo has access to it, but I believe that is as a result of having won the FTC's Robocall Challenge. However, can users of FREESwitch also use this list?

More generally, are there web services (free or paid) that supply a feed of a list (or diff of the list for updates) of these numbers via a web service API?

Comment: You may need to make a FOIA request to the FTC. See [here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1939/1511) for more details.

Comment: [FTC FOIA instructions](https://www.ftc.gov/about-ftc/foia/foia-request), sample letters, etc